# Set cookie from range slider variable in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, range

I can't manage to get my range sliders variable to be set as a cookie, attempting with the current code throws this error [object HTMLSpanElement], other cookies created on the same page, then outputted on another page work fine. Thank you.

```
<div class="""slidecontainer">
  <center>
    <input type="range" min="1500" max="2019" value="2019" class="slider" id="range">
  </center>
  <p>
    <center>Year: <span id="value"></span>
  </p>
  <p>
    <center>OutputVar: <span id="outputVar"></span>
  </p>  
</div>

<script>
  var slider = document.getElementById("range");
  var output = document.getElementById("value");
  var outputVarNo = document.getElementById("outputVar");
  output.innerHTML = slider.value;

  slider.oninput = function() {
    output.innerHTML = this.value;
    outputVarNo = this.value;
    outputVarNo.innerHTML = this.value;
  }

  slider.onchange = function(event){
    var output = document.getElementById("outputVar");
    output.innerHTML = slider.value;
    document.cookie = 'timeChosen + "=" + output' ;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the issue is here - you are appending `output` which is an HTML span element which, when converted to string, gives string output `[object HTMLSpanElement]`.

```
document.cookie = 'timeChosen + "=" + output';
```

I guess you want to write the value to `timeChosen` cookie, which would be written like this:

```
document.cookie = "timeChosen=" + slider.value;
```